# docfx menu missing "Articles", "Api Documentation" when hosted from filesystem but show up on localhost:8080

Tags: asp.net-core, docfx

When I run `docfx docfx.json --serve` and go to `localhost:8080`, I see two items on the top menu: "Articles" and "Api Documentation". When I navigate in the filesystem to `_site\` and click on `index.html` to open it in Chrome, these menu items are missing. How can I make sure the menu is properly set when I run it as a static site?

I need to be able to package the html files and send them to people for them to view locally without them having to download the repo and install docFX.

Comment: Does it help you to look at _site\toc.html?

Comment: When I do that I see (unformatted)
```
[ Enter here to filter ]

* Articles
* Api Documentation
```
And both those pages are missing any navigation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Reason**: The page needs extra JS files to the navigation bar, but it is blocked by Chrome. You can see these errors in Chrome console (F12):

```
docfx.vendor.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/git/docfx-seed/_site/toc.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ docfx.vendor.js:4
docfx.vendor.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/git/docfx-seed/_site/logo.svg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

**Solution**: Use template `statictoc`, which already embedded all the required parts into HTML file:

```
docfx docfx.json -t statictoc
```

Comment: I was beginning to think DocFx wasn't an option... `-t statictoc` fixed it right up.  Thank you!